# Add drush alias with arguments

Tags: drush

I'm working with drush & git and I would like to create a custom drush alias to perform a "git pull" action on a remote server.

This is possibile creating a drushrc.php file in drush home directory with this command:

```
$options['shell-aliases']['git-checkout'] = '!git checkout';
```

So if I run

```
drush @mysite.test git-checkout
```

the system performs a "git checkout" on the test server.

The problem is that I would like to send parameters, like:

```
$options['shell-aliases']['git-checkout'] = '!git checkout %branch';
```

and so:

```
drush @mysite.test git-checkout my_custom_branch
```

should checkout a specific branch.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drush will pass any extra argument in the shell alias to the command. So define the shell alias as:

```
$options['shell-aliases']['git-checkout'] = '!git checkout';
```

and simply run

```
drush @mysite.test git-checkout my_custom_branch
```

Comment: Ok you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is to create not an alias, but a custom command for `drush` ([here are the instructions](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/docs/commands.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use special [shell alias replacements](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drush/plain/docs/shellaliases.html) such as `{{sitealias-item}}`, `{{%pathalias-item}}` or special `{{@target}}`, which is replaced with the name of the site alias
used.

Or maybe instead of trying to create complex alias, try creating [a command file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drush/plain/docs/commands.html) called `COMMANDFILE.drush.inc` (as already suggested by arrubiu).